# How to fix pmdarima straight line predictions

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast the out of sample using pmdarima. However All it produces is a straight line prediction.

The original data_set
[training and validation set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa6sB.png)

And the predictions:
[training and validation set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFZkK.png)
(its a very faint orange line after 2019)

The code for the model:

```
#building the model
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
model = auto_arima(train, trace=True, error_action='ignore', suppress_warnings=True)
model.fit(train)
```

The fit result

```
ARIMA(callback=None, disp=0, maxiter=None, method=None, order=(3, 1, 4),
      out_of_sample_size=0, scoring='mse', scoring_args={},
      seasonal_order=(0, 0, 0, 1), solver='lbfgs', start_params=None,
      suppress_warnings=True, transparams=True, trend=None,
      with_intercept=True)
```

I expect predictions to at least be anything but straight lines.

Comment: There is no long term pattern and information in your data. So, I guess the best it can do, is predict the mean, or a random walk without drift. An ARMA with short lags can converge quickly to predicting the mean in long term forecasts.